# Inequalities (Natural Numbers)

Tags: inequality, number-systems

Suppose that $1 < x$ and $z < x^{z}$ is true where $x, z \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $z + 1 < x^{z+1}$. 
I have tried to use every inequality but have not been able to find the proof. This proof is part of a proof by mathematical induction.

Comment: $z+1 <x^z + 1 \le x^z + x^z = 2*x^z \le x*x^z = x^{z+1} $

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer above is correct with a small correction
$$
x^{z+1} =x^z \times x \ge x^z \times 2 >(z+1) \times2  \ge z+1
$$

If $$ z=0 $$ then 
$$ 
x^{z+1}>z+1 \Longleftrightarrow x^{0+1}> 0+1 \Longleftrightarrow x>1
$$
valid. 
If z>0 then we already know that $$ z + 1 < x^{z+1} $$

Comment: No: the answer is not a mistake because $x^z >z$, not $x^z>z+1$. And $z$ is a natural number, so $z>0$.